# How to dynamically hide radiofield extJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

I tried using the code in
https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0/classic/Ext.form.field.Radio.html

to try making one of the radio fields hidden by adding some configs

```
boxLabel: 'XL',
name: 'size',
inputValue: 'xl',
id: 'radio3',
itemid: 'radio3Id'
```

and changed some code

```
//if XL is selected, change to L
if (radio3.getValue()) {
    radio2.setValue(true);
    return;
    Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#rad3').hidden(true);
}

//if nothing is set, set size to S
radio1.setValue(true);
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#radio3Id').hidden(false);
```

but it does not work. How can I hide the radio field dynamically?
I did not want to use Ext.getCmp() because I plan to remove the id properties of the radio field and using the id property usually causes errors when using it multiple times.

*Edited*
I tried the answers and they all work fine when I use the id property with Ext.getCmp(). I would like this to work with either reference or itemId..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.hidden(true);` or `.hidden(false);` is not the correct method.
You should use `.setHidden(true);` to hide and `.setHidden(false);` to show the component.

Eg: `Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#radio3Id')[0].setHidden(true);`

Hope this info will help you.

Comment: Same with other answers. it works with  Ext.getCmp() but not when i'm using itemId

Comment: Can you please share your code/fiddle (https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor) in which you are getting issue with itemId

Comment: I apologize for not looking clearly at your example. It seems that it actually works when [0] is included in the Ext.ComponentQuery.query. Other answers are so similar that I missed it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [hide()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0/classic/Ext.form.field.Radio.html#method-hide) and [show()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0/classic/Ext.form.field.Radio.html#method-show) methods.

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#radio3Id')[0].hide();
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#radio3Id')[0].show();
```

More complicated example, without using `id` and `itemId`:

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
        Ext.define('Test.TestWindow', {
            extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
            closeAction: 'destroy',
            width: 400,
            height: 400,

            initComponent: function() {
                var me = this;
                me.callParent(arguments);

                me.radioM = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Radio', {
                    boxLabel  : 'M',
                    name      : 'size',
                    inputValue: 'm',
                    width: 50
                });
                me.radioL = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Radio', {
                    boxLabel  : 'L',
                    name      : 'size',
                    inputValue: 'l',
                    width: 50
                });
                me.radioXL = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Radio', {
                    boxLabel  : 'XL',
                    name      : 'size',
                    inputValue: 'xl',
                    width: 50,
                    listeners: {
                        change: function(e) {
                            var me = e.up('window');

                            /**
                            Do what you want with:
                            * me.radioM
                            * me.radioL
                            * me.radioXL
                            */
                            me.radioL.hide();
                        }
                    }
                });

                me.container = Ext.create('Ext.form.FieldContainer', {
                    fieldLabel : 'Size',
                    defaultType: 'radiofield',
                    defaults: {
                        flex: 1
                    },
                    layout: 'hbox',
                    items: [
                        me.radioM,
                        me.radioL,
                        me.radioXL
                    ]
                });

                me.add(me.container);

            }


        });

        var win = new Test.TestWindow({

        });
        win.show();
    }
});
```

Comment: @Jb45           Updated example.

Comment: Thanks for the different approach but I'm marking the other one as it uses itemId

Answer (score 0):

Use **setVisible** function to hide and show the extjs components

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#radio3Id').setVisible(true); //to show
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#radio3Id').setVisible(false); //to hide
```

Comment: I tried using setVisible and it works with  Ext.getCmp() but not with Ext.ComponentQuery.query(). I would like to use the itemId or reference instead of id

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any method called as hidden. setHidden() is the name of method which you can use. You have to pass Boolean value true/false as a parameter. Also hide() and show() will do the job.

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#radio3Id')[0].setHidden(false);//to show
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#radio3Id')[0].setHidden(true);//to hide

Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#radio3Id')[0].show();//to show
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#radio3Id')[0].hide();//to hide
```

Comment: I tried using setHidden and hide and it works with  Ext.getCmp() but not with Ext.ComponentQuery.query()

Comment: Ext.ComponentQuery will return you an array of objects. Edited the answer. try it now.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried with lookupReference ?

Like this :

```
{
 boxLabel: 'XL',
 name: 'size',
 inputValue: 'xl',
 id: 'radio3',
 itemid: 'radio3Id',
 **reference: 'radio3Id'**
}
```

And then :

```
this.lookupReference('radio3Id').setHidden(true);
```

Comment: or maybe with Ext.ComponentQuery.query('itemid="radio3Id"').setHidden(true)